# Can't extract Dates or Timestamps from Firestore DocumentSnapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm retrieving a set of documents of events that contains `Strings`, `Dates` and a `Timestamp`.  `Strings` are no problem but recently I added `Dates` and `Timestamp` to my model they always get returned as nil, which I have set as default, even though I can clearly see in the Firebase console they are stored correctly.

**init setup for DocumentSnapshot retrieval**

```
init?(snapshot:DocumentSnapshot){

    self.eventId = snapshot.get("eventId") as? String ?? "No event Id"
    self.byId = snapshot.get("byId") as? String ?? "No uid"
    self.adminUser = snapshot.get("adminUser") as? String ?? "No admin user"
    //self.eventCreated = snapshot.get("eventCreated") as? Timestamp ?? "No Event Created Date"
    self.eventName = snapshot.get("eventName") as? String ?? "No Event Name"
    self.eventLocation = snapshot.get("eventLocation") as? String ?? "No Location"
    self.eventStart = snapshot.get("eventStart") as? Date ?? nil
    self.eventEnd = snapshot.get("eventEnd") as? Date ?? nil

}
```

**Results from DocumentSnapshot**

```
adminUser: "", 
byId: "juYtTP509rhXYPd433", 
eventCreated: nil, //Timestamp retrieved as nil
eventId: "gC2RVdUuB9CD66JEYM18", 
eventName: "test", 
eventLocation: "", 
eventStart: nil, //Date retrieved as nil
eventEnd: nil, //Date retrieved as nil
```

**Events Model**

```
struct Event {

var adminUser = ""
var byId = ""
var eventCreated:Timestamp?
var eventId = ""
var eventName = ""
var eventLocation = ""
var eventStart:Date? = nil
var eventEnd:Date? =  Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
```

[image: This is the document in the Firebase console]

Please let me know if I need to add the method here for better context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have an internal Date type.  Internally, it will create a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp) when it receives either Dates or Timestamp as input, so that's what your code should expect coming out of DocumentSnapshot in either case (never a Date).

Comment: To convert that `Timestamp` to a `Date`, call its [`dateValue` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#datevalue).

Comment: Will be quite a bit of rework to get this going but I'll start heading in this direction.  Thx